# Not able to read all folders & files available in azure storage container using c#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using below code to read all files available in azure :

```
private const string account = "Testaccount";
private const string key = "I1yMjhk1Pp10KBxU4mnuaxXnsupk3USn8B85TtSunXzO+WLZ+uYbFl/mCkD8Q7yqAA==";
 private const string url = "http://Testaa.blob.core.windows.net/contractattachments/201503/20150302110215315197/20150331114910310626/Test%20-%20Copy%20-%20file.txt";
 private const string containerName = "TestFiles";
 private const string blobName = "File1";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // get storage
            StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey creds = new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(account, key);
            CloudBlobClient blobStorage = new CloudBlobClient(url, creds);

             //get blob container
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobStorage.GetContainerReference(containerName);


            BlobContainerPermissions permissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();
            permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob;
            blobContainer.SetPermissions(permissions);  


             //get blob data
            CloudBlob cloudBlob = blobContainer.GetBlobReference(blobName);
            //string text = cloudBlob.DownloadText();

            // print text
           // Console.WriteLine(text);


            //List blobs and directories in this container
            var blobs = blobContainer.ListBlobs();
            List<string> listofblobs=new List<string>();

            foreach (var blobItem in blobs)// Exception ----The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.
            {
              blobItem.Container.GetPermissions();

            }

            foreach (var blobItem in blobs)
            {

                string BolbName = blobItem.Container.Name.ToString();

                Console.WriteLine(blobItem.Uri);
            }


        }
```

> > >
> >     Actually We have above mentioned storage account and there are containers in that account. Again container contains sub folders and sub folder contains ..some files .....so my requirement is to read all files from available all container ... So first of i was trying to read all files from one container ..but its giving me exception as below 
> >     The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.
> >     Please help me.....Let me know if i am missing anything ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `url` does not point to an Azure Blob Service account even though it is passed to [CloudBlobClient's constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj682550.aspx). Please consider using [CloudStorageAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.cloudstorageaccount.aspx) instead and instantiate [CloudBlobClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient.aspx) using [CreateCloudBlobClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.cloudstorageaccount.createcloudblobclient.aspx).
2. `StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey` was removed in Azure Storage Client Library 2.0, so you are using a very old version. Please consider upgrading to the latest version for performance improvements and bug fixes.

Comment: Thanks For the help , As per suggestion i have storage client lib 2.0 and used below code .CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(accountName, accountPrimaryKey), false);
                       
            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = container.ListBlobs();
            //container.CreateIfNotExist();

Comment: Above plus below code ............  var folders = blobs.Where(b => b as CloudBlobDirectory != null);

            foreach (var folder in folders)
            {
                
                Console.WriteLine(folder.Uri);
            }

           Now i have question how to read each and every files from folder...i am able to read each folder within container ...but how to get each files

Comment: `StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey` does not exist in later versions, so you might want to double check you are using the latest version. If you want to list everything, you can pass in `useFlatBlobListing=true` to `ListBlobs`, which will return all blobs in the container instead of emulating a directory structure.

Comment: Thanks i have tried to use             IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs2 = container.ListBlobs(blobPrefix, useFlatBlobListing, BlobListingDetails.None);................Getting error ...saying no overloaded method for ListBlob take 3 arguments

Comment: Also tried below code IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs3 = blobContainer.ListBlobs(new BlobRequestOptions()
            {
                UseFlatBlobListing = false,
            });

            var folders1 = blobs3.Where(b => b as CloudBlobDirectory != null).ToList();             ============> which is only returning folders ...i want list of all files from folder??

Comment: `UseFlatBlobListing` should be true. And the reason you couldn't find the other overload is that you are using a very old library.

Comment: I am using storage client library 2.0 ....so do you have any idea ...how can write code for this ...or do i need to change library entirely

Comment: Did you try `UseFlatBlobListing=true` in `BlobRequestOptions`?